# Series for roots

Tags: asymptotics

The sequence of polynomial equations
$$
(a+n)x^n+(b-n)x^{n-1}+f(n)=0
$$

has real roots near 1 having an asymptotic series
$$
x_n=1+\frac{y_n-a-b}{n}+O(y_n^2n^{-2}),
$$
where
$$
y_n=W(-e^{a+b}f(n)).
$$
Here $W$ is the Lambert function.

---

Now, I want to apply this result to the special sequence of polynomials
$$
x^n-x^{n-1}-1=0.
$$
So I guess I have to choose
$$
a=1-n,\qquad b=n-1,\qquad f(n)=-1.
$$

Then I should have by above
$$
x_n=1+\frac{y_n}{n}+O(y_n^2n^{-2})
$$
with $y_n=W(1)$.

On the other hand, I know that
$$
x_n\sim1+\frac{\log n}{n}.
$$

Do these two results fit together?
Maybe $y_n=W(1)$ is equivalent to $y_n=\log(n)$?

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, the difference $W(1) - \log(n)$ grows as $n$ increases.  That difference does have zero near $n = 2$ where you could call them approximately equal, I guess.  As $n$ gets large, both $\frac{W(1)}{n}$ and $\frac{\log(n)}{n}$ get squashed to 0 anyway.

Comment: If you want to try something different than the Lambert function approach, you may be able to modify Glasser's approach to finding the roots of $x^n-x-t=0$, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700002879 .  But it might not work out so well.  I'll note that your polynomial can be written as $x^{n-1}(x-1) - 1 = 0$, which is kind of interesting, in that the roots are close to the $n^{th}$ roots of unity.

Comment: The Lambert function approach would be faster and simpler, since you can precompute $W(1)$. That is assuming you only want the real root near 1.

Comment: I think $x_n$ is the largest positive real root, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes.  The roots are arranged in nearly a circle in the complex plane, close to the $n^{th}$ roots of unity.  The root near 1 is the largest real root.  Wolfram Alpha gives you a nice plot.  Here's the case for $n=8$ for example:  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E7(x-1)-1%3D0